# Why I can not acces $scope value from MainController within index.cshtml?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create AngularJS, MVC ASP.Net single page application so
I have created new folder within my project which contains 
app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
```

and another folder containing MainController.js:

```
myApp.controller("MainController",['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.naslov = "MP3 Manager"}]);
```

next, inside Views/Home I have added this in my div tag

```
 ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController"
```

and finally I got this:

```
<div class="row" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Pjesme</h2>
    <p>{{ naslov }}</p>
    <p>
        ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
        enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
        for enjoyable, agile development.
    </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Playliste</h2>
    <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

when I run this app it shows `{{ naslov }}` instead of `"MP3 Manager"`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoSBo.jpg

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you looked for any error messages your browser is flagging up? look for the developer tools. This behavior can happen for a huge amount of reasons from syntax errors - incorrect imports

Comment: Did you put a script reference at the top of your .cshtml page to your app and your controller?

Comment: @Harvey any idea?
https://imgur.com/iDUYRvK

Comment: Yep, you haven't referenced your app.js file properly in your html file, ensure your `<script>` tag points directly to your app.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to Angularjs, your app and your controller.  I usually put the Angularjs reference and my app reference in my Layout.cshtml page, then the controller reference on the .cshtml page.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/MainController.js"></script>
```

You need all three.

Answer (score 0):

maby you can try `<p ng-model="naslov ">{{naslov }}<p>`

Comment: that is most certainly a solution to the question. it may not be the correct solution, and it could use some explaining, but it is an answer. lastly, "providing answers that don't require clarification from the asker"...asker can plug an answer like that in and get a desired solution, so this doesn't require clarification. how about being more friendly and welcoming to n00bs?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I agree with Martin Welker. You can't declare `ngApp` and `ngController` on the same element. It is not good practice.
Secondly check whether Angular is properly loaded. You could have a problem in your BundleConfig.cs file. Small typos can cause these silly errors.
Run it and check your browser console for any errors.

Comment: It may not be good practice, but you definitely can put ngApp and ngController on the same element.  I actually have never heard that it's bad practice.  I do it on mini-SPAs.  Full SPA applications I structure differently.